# Can a person do only Bhakti in his life ? Or Is engaging in wordly activities also necessary?

Tags: krishna, bhakti, gita

Gita is the ultimate book to know how should one live his life.
Gita focuses on Karma Yoga and in Gita Krishna asks Arjun to engage in war i.e. Krishna didn't tell Arjun to do only Bhakti of him.
I am asking if in Gita or anywhere Krishna or for that matter any god has said that engaging in worldly activities is also necessary apart from Bhakti to the God ?

Although some examples exist of such persons who used to do only bhakti of God and not anything else eg- Mirabai, who abandoned her worldly duties and used to do only Bhakti of Krishna.
Not sure, but I think Prahalad is also such a example.

So, My question is Can a person do only bhakti of god and not do anything else in his life ?
Or Is engaging in worldy affairs also necessary ?

Comment: Pl refer *Vyadha Gita* and *Jivanmukta Gita* (one of two primary gitas by Lord Dattatreya). It is usually a sin to refrain from one's duties and give spiritual exercises as excuses. But one can still make his/her way to liberation through it.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Yeah Arjun was also told by Krishna not to give up his duties. But What about Mirabai ? Is Mirabai story authentic ?

Comment: Yes. Mirabai's story is authentic.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha But Mirabai gave up her marital duties, but still got Moksha.

Comment: You can simply get moksha by not doing anything also, forget bhakti. But material duties are also equally important. You can get moksha by becoming a sanyaasi too (*karm sanyaas yog*), but performing duty is important and superior.https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/5 Check verse 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bhagavad Gita 18.66

> सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज।
> अहं त्वा सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुचः।।18.66।।

> 18.66 Completely relinishing all Dharmas (duties), seek Me (Krishna/Vishnu) alone for refuge. I will release you from all sins. Grieve not.

So yes, a person can be a bhakta of God without doing anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Narada Purana Gives the Following Answer.

> **[Narada Purana I.15.152-157](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12945/page/n275/mode/2up?view=theater)**

[image]

[image]

Here clearly performance of one's duties is encouraged alongside Devotion.

Answer (score -1):

The only lokaa where Bhakthi is ALL-TIME is Swarga Lokaa. In Bhoolokaa, during KaliYuga it is advised to follow VARNAASHRAMA DHARMA to attain liberation.

```
  ENJOYING EARTH ---) DIFFICULT
```

Though Earth is very beautiful, one cannot fully enjoys its wonders as human born. While enjoying it beauty a human may be subjected to either purity or sins by more glowing minds of primitive humans, animals and others.

```
            STAGES ---)
```

(Karma Nyana Nyaasa Vibhaga Bhakthi) yogas are needed to attain liberation.

Comment: Swarg Loka is to enjoy the benefits of your good Karmas. So, it is a materialistic place. Once the karma is over you are back to Mrityu Loka!

Answer (score -1):

What is your end goal? Bhakti or Moksha? If your goal is Moksha, you will need to let go of God and Bhakti at the end.

God will not like you if you escape your duties. If you are a household you need to take care of your family. Do your duties without ego. For more information read how Gita explains Nishkam Karmayoga.

TIP: If you serve humanity (without ego) you are serving God.